# PHPUnit testing insert to db by a class

Tags: database, phpunit

I have created a testing class with a function to test a specific action:

```
public function testdoAddItem()
{
    $this->assertEquals(0, $this->getConnection()->getRowCount('article'), "Pre-Condition");

    #$tableNames = array('article');
    #$dataSet = $this->getConnection()->createDataSet($tableNames);

    $article = new article();
    $article->constructChanger(1, 1, 'Article');
    $article->doAddItem();

    $this->assertEquals(2, $this->getConnection()->getRowCount('article'), "Inserting failed");
}
```

I get a first assert result as true, which it should be, but I dont see the second return that should return failed assert. All I see is a blank output.

Here is my doAddItem():

```
    $pageid = $this->pageid;
    $schoolid = crud::quote($_POST['schoolid']);
    $newvalue = crud::quote(strip_tags($_POST['addareatext']));
    $title = crud::quote($_POST['title']);

    // Inserting the new article
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `article`(`id`, `pageid`, `school_id`, `title`, `content`) 
            VALUES ('', '" . $pageid . "', {$schoolid}, {$title}, {$newvalue});";
    $result = crud::rawSelect($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with the routing with in the system. For some reason PHPUnit doesn't like "define(SOMETHING, $something)"; which created range of errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is derived from the answer of user1652382.

PHPUnit uses single process for each test, so if you have defines somewhere in your system, and that is initialized for example using `setUp()` or by some class you use in the tests, define will be defined twice, which makes PHP soundly die.

There is means to run all tests separately, but I found it to be pretty fragile, so I resulted having separate `init.php`, which loads core stuff, which does the defines per test basis.